# How can i get part of a url with php?

Tags: php

I want to only load script when it needed and am currently using php.

```
<?php 
    $page = basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    if ($page == 'shows.php' || $page == "/" || $page == '') {
?>
<script></script>
```

What is the best practice for excluding script? Would excluding script help load time?
If anyone has other suggestions I would be glad to hear them.

Problem: I want to get show.php from the url

```
http://www.turbosaw.com/shows.php?action=viewShow&showId=30
```

My previous php url query (what i'm calling it till someone corrects me), doesn't work, and I assume it's because it has all that extra stuff behind php.

Any ideas?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

Comment: or `$url = "http://www.turbosaw.com/shows.php?action=viewShow&showId=30"; $url = explode("?",basename($url));
echo $url[0];`

Comment: Are you loading a large number of or a lot of very large scripts? if not then it is probably overkill especially as they are then already cached on the next page rather than processing repeatedly to see if this page needs it and if that page needs it etc

Comment: I have a separate scripts.php that i'm running all my script snippets in. I'm thinking this may be bad practice because I've never seen it done. Also, this scripts.php is only 11kb so it might be overkill to do this

Comment: `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']` should give the right information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Firstly, yes you can use `parse_url()`, so this answer is more aimed at what you do with that once you've actually gotten it, which is the easy part.

You *could* just check that "shows.php" is contained within the url string:

```
if (stristr($url, 'shows.php')) { ...
```

*Note: stristr() is case insensitive, strstr() is case sensitive*

However, this doesn't look like the best way of doing things. You could be using regex to do this as well, but really it looks like you're trying to figure out some sort of routing mechanism.

What you *could* do is something like [Symfony2's routing mechanism](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html), which is have a pre-built "map" of routes to check for. It looks like you aren't using a framework and won't be anytime soon, so here's a simple suggestion:

Have an include file that simply checks if the url is in an array of url's, and if it is, output the code to include the JavaScript file.

```
$routes = array(
    '/',
    '/shows.php'
);
```

You could loop around the array and check if any of these routes is in the url, and do as you wish (ie, include the JS file):

```
foreach ($routes as $route)
{
    if (in_array($route, $yourURL))
    {
        // Include your JS file here
        break;
    }
}
```

Do that in **one file**. Include it at the top of your script in a sort of 'bootstrap', and then you won't have to duplicate this check on every single page you use. You just include the 'check file'.

Comment: This looks like an excellent solution! I'm going to try it out

Comment: The OP was looking a way to extract the script name from an URL, aka parsing. `strstr()` is really unsafe for that matter. I'm not sure implementing a routing system akin to symfony is really what the OP needs.

Comment: @thibauts OP has two questions, the final one being the equivalent of "how do I parse for this from the url" - which other answers provided. The first question OP asks is the equivalent of "I want to only load a script when it is needed". Therefore, I provided the answer to the firsr one, in-depth and with more effort than I should have really, and pointed to a simple function from other's questions (`parse_url()`) for the simple parsing. Read the first and second sentences of the question, and then OP's thankfulness at a good answer to his or her question.

Comment: @thibauts Oh and as for your comment about it being unsafe, maybe (if you can read English so well) you should check out the words "You could [do it this way]", in italics for emphasis, and also "however, this doesn't look like the best way of doing things".

Comment: The OP is trying to conditionnaly echo a `<script></script>` tag based on the current requested PHP script. What he is really looking for is PHP_SELF IMO.

Comment: Which is why I tout my advice as just that: advice. This is intentional, and repeatedly expressed with, for example, the words "What you could do" and "here's a simple suggestion". If you consider the above example a "full blown routing / front controller solution", well.. just no. Perhaps you should write your own answer here. OP found what he was looking for, hence he marked the answer as correct.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) function in PHP.

```
$url = "http://www.turbosaw.com/shows.php?action=viewShow&showId=30";

$parsed_url = parse_url($url);
$path = $parsed_url['path']; // '/shows.php'

//Now to take off front '/'
$path = substr($path, 1); // 'shows.php'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the filename of the script using PHP magic constants:

ie `echo __FILE__;` would give you shows.php for the above URL

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP's built-in [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) function.

```
$url = 'http://www.turbosaw.com/shows.php?action=viewShow&showId=30';
print_r(parse_url($url));
```

Would output:

```
Array
(
    [scheme] => http
    [host] => turbsaw.com
    [path] => /path
    [query] => action=viewShow&showId=30
)
```

You can get your own server and page's addresses if you look into the `$_SERVER` array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) function for that purpose.

**Code:**

```
<?php

$url = "http://www.turbosaw.com/shows.php?action=viewShow&showId=30";
var_dump(parse_url($url));

?>
```

**Output:**

```
array(4) {
  ["scheme"]=>
  string(4) "http"
  ["host"]=>
  string(16) "www.turbosaw.com"
  ["path"]=>
  string(10) "/shows.php"
  ["query"]=>
  string(25) "action=viewShow&showId=30"
}
```

Hope this helps.